# .htaccess to restrict access by file type

Tags: http, .htaccess

I don't have too much experience with .htaccess files and I would like one that disallows access (403 Forbiden) to `.myext` files in a folder and all its sub-folders.

Can anyone write me a quick rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`<FilesMatch>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#filesmatch) and [`Deny`](http://php.net/http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#deny):

```
<FilesMatch "\.myext$">
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

You also might need to change the [order of how `Allow` and `Deny` rules are applied](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order).

Another option would be to use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .+\.myext$ - [F]
```

To have these directives only be applied on specific directories, put them into the .htaccess file of that specific directory. With mod_rewrite you could also specify the path within the rule pattern like:

```
RewriteRule ^foo/bar/.+\.myext$ - [F]
```

Comment: Rewrites are done through `mod_rewrite`, whereas `FilesMatch` is included in core (if you can't/won't load `mod_rewrite`): http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#filesmatch

Comment: Thank you. I used the FilesMatch method. Also do you have any idea why a server would ignore the rule?

Comment: @Alin Purcaru: Ignore what rule?

Comment: @Gumbo Ignore the *FilesMatch* with *Deny from all* **Directive** (I saw now that that's how I should call it) and allow access to .myext files. I tested on 3 servers, but one of them allowed access. All of them were Apache. I'm sorry if I can't explain myself better, but my experience with servers is almost 0.

Comment: @Alin Purcaru: It might be that the .htaccess file is ignored. Some web servers do only respect the .htaccess file in the document root directory but no other (for performance reasons).

Comment: @Gumbo It wasn't that. Any other options?

Comment: @Alin Purcaru: Maybe you’re not [allowed to override](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) with `Deny`.

Comment: There aren't any other .htaccess files. Also I tried another .htaccess with a mod_rewrite rule an that one didn't apply either. Could it be that all .htaccess files are ignored?

Comment: @Alin Purcaru: Yes, that’s possible too.